# Using Moq: mock object throwing 'TargetParameterCountException'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am new to Moq, so hopefully I am just missing something here.  For some reason I am getting a TargetParameterCountException.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?  Any questions?  Please ask. :)

Here's my code:

```
[Test]
  public void HasStudentTest_SaveToRepository_Then_HasStudentReturnsTrue()
  {
     var fakeStudents = new List<Student>();
     fakeStudents.Add(new Student("Jim"));

     mockRepository.Setup(r => r.FindAll<Student>(It.IsAny<Predicate<Student>>()))
                                .Returns(fakeStudents.AsQueryable<Student>)
                                .Verifiable();

     // in persistence.HasStudent(), repo.FindAll(predicate) is throwing 
     // 'TargetParameterCountException' ; not sure why
     persistence.HasStudent("Jim");
     mockRepository.VerifyAll();
  }
```

Here's the HasStudent method from Persistence:

```
public bool HasStudent(string name)
  {
     // throwing the TargetParameterCountException
     var query = Repository.FindAll<Student>(s => s.Name == name); 

     if (query.Count() > 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("There should not be multiple Students with the same name.");

     return query.Count() == 1;
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you substitue It.IsAny<Predicate...> for It.IsAny<object>() ?

Comment: @Kirschstein: that won't compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the signature of the FindAll method? Does your repository have overloaded FindAll methods?

If so, that *may* be the explanation. Your lamda expression can compile into several different types, such as `Predicate<Student>`, `Func<Student, bool>` or `Expression<Func<Student, bool>>`.

I'm not sure I understand exeactly what is going on, but TargetParameterCountException is a type that belongs to the System.Reflection namespace, so that indicates that Moq somehow tries to invoke a method with the wrong number of arguments. The most common cause for that is when members are overloaded and the wrong overload ends up being invoked...

Comment: Ahhhh...  I see.  There is also a FindAll() overload.

Comment: Now how can I get around this without removing the FindAll() ?

Comment: also, the signature is this: IQueryable<T> FindAll<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) { }

Comment: or: IQueryable<T> FindAll<T>() {}

Comment: Hmm... In that case, your Setup looks quite unambiguous, so I don't quite understand what's going on. Are both methods virtual/abstract?

Comment: neither are virtual or abstract.

Comment: ...but, to Moq them, they must be... Do they form part of an interface implementation, then (which amounts to the same thing)?

Answer (score 6):

This is way late to the question but for the sake of Googlers...

I have a very similar case, and I can't explain why, but the problem seems to be with calling AsQueryable on a generic List inside the .Returns().  Problem was solved by setting up the List as IQueryable before the mock setup.  Something like...

```
var fakeList = new List<foo>.AsQueryable();
...
mockRepository.Setup(r => r.FindAll<foo>(It.IsAny<foo>()))
                            .Returns(fakeList)
                            .Verifiable();
```

Comment: Had this problem also and your post helped me alot. Thanks m8!